# What is difference between managed and unmanaged data providers in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

We have different data providers like SqlClient,OracleClient,OLEDB,ODBC.Among them which are managed and which are unmanaged and whats difference between them ?

Comment: Practically all dbase providers are unmanaged, most dbase engines have been around a long, long time.  All of the ones you listed are.  With a managed wrapper for them to make them easy to use from managed code.  So it is *both*.

Comment: @HansPassant `SqlClient` is entirely managed.

Comment: It is not, chunks of System.Data were written in C++/CLI.  Just look at SNI_ConnWrapper for example, a native C++ class that leaked into the assembly metadata.  SNI is the SQL Server Network Interface protocol.

Answer (score 0):

They are all managed.  For the differences, see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)